# C fat pointer implementation failure

Tags: c, pointers

I have discovered a [library](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stretchy_buffer.h) recently which implements a C++ vector like functionality using fat pointers.

I have tried to replicate a similar behaviour in a short program (see the code below). I can access the array elements fine but when I try to get the number of elements my program prints garbage.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double * a = NULL;

    // the data
    double b[] = {1, 2, 3, 5};

    a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) + sizeof(double *));
    a[0] = 4;
    a++;
    a = b;

    // will print 1.0 2.0 3.0 5.0
    printf("%lf %lf %lf %lf\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    // prints garbage
    printf("%d\n", *((int *) a - 1));

    // this will fail
    free(((int *) a - 1))
    return 0;
}
```

It is likely that the problem lies in the pointer arithmetic part of the code, i.e. `(int *) a - 1` points to the wrong address, but I could not figure out why is that the case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This code is just wildly undefined behavior, anything can happen. There is no predictable outcome of this code to be had. Instead use structs, possible with a _flexible array member_ at the end.

Comment: I would throw this code in the bin. 1. What does this mean ` a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) + sizeof(double *));` - Why the cast and what are you . trying to achieve. 2. Playing around with `a` and then ` free(((int *) a - 1))` as you state it will fail The code is a mess - bin it.

Comment: Your a++ is being done with a double sized amount, so you're moving (probably) 8 bytes, instead of (probably) 4.  You possibly also have alignment problems.  x86 doesn't require doubles on 8-byte boundaries, but other architectures might.

Comment: Doing this to not be undefined behaviour probably requires a struct that looks like struct { int size; char prefix[1] }, using the extendable structure paradigm.  Then return a pointer to prefix.  Getting your pointer back is probably still difficult.  Still potential alignment problems.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the answer. The reason I wanted to use fat pointers because this way I can use any data type (int, float, ...) with the fat pointer (given that `sizeof(double *)` is exchanged to `sizeof(int *)` or `sizeof(float *)` and so on.

Comment: Also your a=b just reassigns your pointer to b, and you've lost it.  You need to memcpy().

Comment: You want to implement a lightweight version of `C++ vector` in C? I would start with defining the interface, what do you expect from that thing? If you know what you want, it makes sense to think about the implementation. BTW: what is a fat pointer, when do you use thin pointer?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I was trying to replicate the behaviour of the library mentioned in the description because I was interested in its inner workings. I am working on the program based on the answers, once I solved the problem I will post it as an answer. Again thanks for the help! (Fat pointer explained [here](http://libcello.org/learn/a-fat-pointer-library))

Answer (score 0):

Packing the length at the beginning of the array is not a fat pointer, but an ill-formed PASCAL array.

```
int main(fat_pointer);

int main(int argc, char* argv[argc]); // standard signature for main is a fat pointer
```

A fat pointer is a pointer and an index. The data type of the index is an integral type which guarantees that `sizeof index <= sizeof(size_t)`. In other words, `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(size_t)` is a mandate for all compliant hosted environment because `main` demands so. Note that `size_t` is not defined for freestanding environment.

The problem with `_s` functions is that they use `sal.h` from Microsoft which allow the usage of variables before declaration.

```
char * strcpy_s(char * restrict dest, rsize_t destsz, char const * restrict src);

// fat pointer form fails
char * strcpy_s(char dest[destsz], rsize_t destsz, char const * src);
```

The fat pointer form fails because destsz is declared afterwards, so it cannot be used. Annex K is horrible because it has usage before declaration in fat pointer form. Look at `main` where `argc` is declared before `argv`; that is the proper way to declare a fat pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void print_vector_double(int len, double d[len])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("%lf ", d[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d\n", len);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[argc])
{
    // C89 VLA - initialized VLA
    double b[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5, };
    int b_len = (int)(sizeof b / sizeof b[0]);
    print_vector_double(b_len, b);

    // C99 VLA - uninitialized VLA
    int c_len = b_len;
    double c[c_len];
    c = b;
    print_vector_double(c_len, c);

    // Good Old Heap for Dynamic Arrays
    int a_len = b_len;
    double * a = malloc(a_len * sizeof * a);
    double * temp = memcpy(a, b_len * sizeof * b, b);
    if (temp != a) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    print_vector_double(a_len, a);

    free(a), a = NULL, a_len = 0;
}
```

A fat pointer is what you pass to a function. If you are not passing anything to another function, there is no fat pointer.

Cello failed to understand what a fat pointer really is.